# How do I pass class objects as parameters in a method?

Tags: java

I am new to Java. I have a Fruit class (name and price are my instance variables) and FruitBasket (3 instance variable of Fruit f1, f2, f3).

I am trying to create a swap method that takes 3 Fruit objects as parameters. Please provide me with a a simple answer as this is an assignment.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
Please see: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Comment: What exactly should the `swap` method do? Can you show us what you have tried so far with a code example?

Comment: Explain, draw or make a photo of the "basket" and what should happen when "swapping the fruits". So we can understand the task and guide you in solving. See how a [similar Fruit-Basket question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59220568/table-array-manipulation-to-consolidate-multi-column-selection) clearly explains _given input_ and _expected output_ of a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing an object as a parameter is a lot like passing any other parameter. You just need to use the name of the object class, in your case `Fruit`, in place of any other variable type.

It's also a lot like how you would define the instance variables of type `Fruit` in your `FruitBasket` class.

For example, if you have a method signature like so:

```
public void swap(int f1, int f2){}
```

You can just replace the keyword `int` with the keyword `Fruit` or whatever your object class name is.

```
public void swap(Fruit f1, Fruit f2, Fruit f3){}
```